# rotation to original position in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was making a game where there is a plane which I control using the wasd keys, it rotates and translates. Up-to that its fine, but I would like the plane to re-align to its original rotation when I lift the key. The code I made up is this but it doesn't work. The plane realigns for only one frame and then "misaligned" again . This is the code -**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class planemovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int fspeed = 10;
    float horizontal; float zrot;
    float vertical; float yrot;
    public float sense; public int lim = 0; 
    void Start()
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float rotz = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); float roty = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * fspeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * sense * Time.deltaTime * horizontal*20f);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * sense * Time.deltaTime * vertical);
        zrot -= rotz;
        yrot -= roty;
        zrot = Mathf.Clamp(zrot, -lim, lim);
        yrot = Mathf.Clamp(yrot, -lim, lim);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(zrot, 0f, yrot);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotation in Unity C# is usually quite wonky, the only time it is exact is when you use Quaternions properly.

```
public Quaternion startQuaternion;

void Start() {
    startQuaternion = transform.rotation;
}

//when you want to reset to original
transform.rotation = startQuaternion;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand, but if you using a rigidbody, you can try using "Quaternion.Lerp" and MoveRotation.
Quaternion.Lerp has three parameters and creates a rotation from point A to B, with a speed ugual to T (T goes from 0 to 1).

```
  var currentRot = transform.rotation
var desired Rot = rotation on which the plane must be aligned
Quaternion RotPlane = Quaternion.Lerp (currentRot, desiredRot, 0.5)
MoveRotation(RotPlane)
```

You can use an if (Input.GetKeyUp) and put the script underneath it, so every time you release the buttons the plane returns to the desired rotation.